# parse text into sentences via regex

Tags: regex

I want to split a text into sentences. For a simple case, I have the following code:

```
Regex.Split (input, @ "(? <= [\.! \?])");
```

However, this only handles sentences that end with a single character, whereas I want to be able to handle sentences that end with any of ".", "...", "!", "!..", "?", "?..", "?!", "?!.", "!?", "!?.", "‽" or "‽..".

For the simple case with only "." and "...", for example "The quick brown fox. Simple way to go abc ... Qwerty.", I've written the following code:

```
string [] sentences = Regex.Split (input, @ "(? <= \. \. \. | \.)");
```

However, this splits the string up as below:

- The quick brown fox.
- Simple way to go abc.
- .
- .
- Qwerty.

Whereas I want this:

- The quick brown fox.
- Simple way to go abc...
- Qwerty.

How should I write a regex to do this?

**So the solution**

```
(?<=\.)\s*(?=[^.])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH4nD3/5)

Comment: you have spaces in between the periods in your pattern, and why are you looking a look around? try something like `\.\.\.|\.` without the lookbehind or spaces (EDIT: i get why you want the lookbehind now. but get rid of the spaces)

Comment: In general, I'm not sure a regular expression will be powerful enough. How, for example, how would you split `Mr. Smith couldn't understand his regex. He searched StackOverflow, etc. but found nothing.`?

Comment: But then the string will without a points. And I need a strings with points

Comment: Look for some NLP library, if you are not doing this just for fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating @Avinash's regex, `(?<=\.)\s*(?=[^.])` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH4nD3/5)) should solve your problem.

Explanation:

- `(?<=\.)` asserts that the following string is preceded by a dot
- `\s*` matches zero or more white space characters (discarding them in a replace)
- `(?=[^.])` asserts that the string is followed by any string that is not a dot (so multiple dots are ignored)

Comment: You should still include the regex in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add in a lookahead to make sure that there is a sentence ending mark, the match all the spaces and marks:

```
(?= *[.!?])([ .?!]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pA9jE4/2)

Comment: Displays a sentence, then the dots